# Unable to connect to SQL Server 2012 in a LAN

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to access a SQL Server database from another computer in a **LAN**.

Local SQL server instance is `SQLEXPRESS` and that of remote computer is `MSSQLSERVER`. Using ip address and User ID and Password in Local SQL Server, I am able to connect to database of remote server directly but trying to connect it from connection string in C# Windows Forms application throws an error in decrypt function:

> Invalid length for a base-64 char array or string

I get this error only when I try connecting to the SQL Server remotely. I don't get this error while connecting to local database.

My connection string in Visual Studio 2015 :

```
<add name="TheConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=192.168.100.4;Initial Catalog=cafePOSdb;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=admin;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I enabled remote connections in SQL Server on the remote computer, enabled TCP/IP in SQL Server Configuration Manager also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What line does this occur on? Can you post the code please. I suspect it has nothing to do with the connection and is some other error

Comment: byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

Comment: cipherText is admin when I run the application

Comment: I don't see any correlation between this bit of code and a database connection.

Comment: really sorry sir.I got my answer. I should have used encrypted password in connection string . I did  so in past for security purpose but forgot that small thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
```

Please check your `cipherText` variable has 4 digit number.